# javascript how to return a value from event function to outer function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, return

Can someone please help me with this. I what to return var from input event function to outer function.

```
function takeInputText() {

    var input = document.getElementById('inputText')
    var newText;

    input.onkeyup = function(e) {

        var text = input.value;
        if ( e.which == 13 ) {
            newText = text;
            input.value = '';
            //return newText  - I want to return 'newText' to 'takeInputText()' so i can 
                               // use 'takeInputText()' as a variable
        }
    }   
}
takeInputText();
```

Comment: What's your problem ? `newText` variable can be accessible from the `takeInputText()` method also.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, but a good hint is [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: What you want to do with that input ? I assume you are going by wrong direction...

Comment: _"I want to return 'newText' to 'takeInputText()' so i can 
                               // use 'takeInputText()' as a variable"_ What would `takeInputText` be passed to?

Comment: To help you understand the answers, what you want to do is not possible in the form you're asking about. The `onkeyup` function is *asynchronous*. It isn't called at the same time as your other code, it is called *later* when the user hits and releases a key. So you can't "return" a value, because there is nothing to return it to. Instead, as shown in the various answers, to use `newText` somewhere else in your code, you have to *call a function* and pass it as an argument to that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to play with the value of the input once user hit enter key, bind `keyup` event over input and manipulate the value in the callback function.
 You can also call another function in which value of the input could be passed.

**Example:**

```js
var input = document.getElementById('inputText');
input.onkeyup = function(e) {
  var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (code == 13) {
    appendInput(this.value);
    this.value = '';
  }
}

function appendInput(value) {
  var elem = document.createElement('h2');
  elem.textContent = value;
  document.getElementById('preview').appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputText">
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `takeInputText()` as a variable since what you are doing inside `takeInputText` is just attaching a `keyup` listener to the `input` element and the function returns immediately (`undefined` is returned in this case).

To make use of the value, pass the variable as an argument to a function that you want to invoke when the condition inside the handler is true, for example:

```
input.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var text = input.value;
    if ( e.which == 13 ) {
        input.value = '';
        yourFunction(text);
    }
}
```